# Configure Apache Mass Virtual Hosts to different directories

Tags: apache-2.2, directory, virtualization, hosts, hard-drive

Our server is running Apache on port 9000 (because IIS is at 80) and we have the following configuration (vhosts.conf) to access our sites:

```
NameVirtualHost *:9000
UseCanonicalName Off

<VirtualHost *:9000>
    ServerAlias %1.ourserver
    VirtualDocumentRoot D:/oursites/%1
    VirtualScriptAlias D:/oursites/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

So we can open the browser and access by `http://someclient.ourserver:9000/`. So far so good.

Now we are installing a new server, where Apache will run on port 80, but we need that **one** specific site to have the `VirtualDocumentRoot` to a different drive/directory. We tried something like this (with no success):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
UseCanonicalName Off

<VirtualHost specificsite.ourdomain.com:80>
    ServerAlias specificsite.ourdomain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot C:/specificsite
    VirtualScriptAlias C:/specificsite
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias %1.ourserver
    VirtualDocumentRoot D:/oursites/%1
    VirtualScriptAlias D:/oursites/%1
</VirtualHost>
```

When we test, the result is that, accessing `http://specificsite.ourdomain.com/` on browser, Apache tries to "redirect" to `D:/oursites/specificsite`, which **is not correct**.

Accessing `http://someclient.ourserver/` Apache redirects **correctly** to `D:/oursites/someclient`.

So what am I missing? Looks like I am forgetting a little detail that is resulting in all requests falling at the second VirtualHost.

*More info:*

- Running Xampp 1.7.7 *on*
- Windows Server 2008 R2 *with*
- Two entries on DNS management: one for the *.ourserver and another for the specificsite.ourdomain.com;
- The reason of using `specificsite.ourdomain.com` is that our clients can access this specific site that is hosted on our server.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `ServerAlias` doesn't support the same variables as `VirtualDocumentRoot` - that vhost's alias is set to literally `%1.ourserver`.
2. Your declaration of the new vhost doesn't match the `NameVirtualHost` directive, so it's not being checked when a request comes in on that host/port combination.  It's using DNS to find the address to bind to, so the fact that it didn't knock the dynamic vhost offline means that your server's probably behind a NAT.

Try this:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

# Put this one's configuration first, so that it's the default.
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Add a ServerName directive so that it doesn't guess - it can be anything
    ServerName dynamic.filler.name
    ServerAlias *.ourserver
    VirtualDocumentRoot D:/oursites/%1
    VirtualScriptAlias D:/oursites/%1
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName specificsite.ourdomain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot C:/specificsite
    VirtualScriptAlias C:/specificsite
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I will test this configuration as soon as possible (maybe tonight (in 2 hours) or tomorrow at noon because I can't put the new server in the network with everybody using the old one), but it looks good.

Comment: Can I buy you a beer? Your code worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)